# Exception in thread "main" org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.bson.BsonElement

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, mongo-scala-driver

I am getting below exception :
Exception in thread "main" org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.bson.BsonElement.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:51)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.IterableCodec.org$mongodb$scala$bson$codecs$IterableCodec$$writeValue(IterableCodec.scala:71)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.IterableCodec$$anonfun$writeIterable$1.apply(IterableCodec.scala:87)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.IterableCodec$$anonfun$writeIterable$1.apply(IterableCodec.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.IterableCodec.writeIterable(IterableCodec.scala:87)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.IterableCodec.org$mongodb$scala$bson$codecs$IterableCodec$$writeValue(IterableCodec.scala:69)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.IterableCodec.encode(IterableCodec.scala:58)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.IterableCodec.encode(IterableCodec.scala:51)
    at com.mongodb.client.model.BuildersHelper.encodeValue(BuildersHelper.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.client.model.Updates$SimpleUpdate.toBsonDocument(Updates.java:445)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.Operations.toBsonDocument(Operations.java:489)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.Operations.findOneAndUpdate(Operations.java:285)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncOperations.findOneAndUpdate(AsyncOperations.java:147)

Tried with applying different types of encoders but no success. Need how to use codec for BsonElement

Below is the code which gives above mentioned runtime Exception:

```
        val mongoClient= MongoClient(uriString)
        val db = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName)
        val collection = db.getCollection(collectionName)
        var caseDBObj = new ListBuffer[BsonElement]()
        caseDBObj += new BsonElement("Key1", new BsonString("Value1"))
        caseDBObj += new BsonElement("Key2", new BsonString("Value2"))
        caseDBObj += new BsonElement("Key3", new BsonString("Value3"))
        val observableDoc = collection
        .findOneAndUpdate(
            equal("id", "1234"), 
            addToSet("ban_case_tkt", caseDBObj)
         )
         observableStatus(observableDoc)
         val awaitedR = Await.result(observableDoc.toFuture, Duration.Inf)
```

Below code works :

```
            val observableDoc = collection
            .findOneAndUpdate(
            equal("id", "1234"), 
            addToSet("ban_case_tkt", "test11"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Codec` for `BsonElement` and that is why you are encountering an error. I would recommend just using a `BsonDocument` otherwise you will have to create and register a custom `Codec`.